# sagemaker.estimator.Estimator containers eu-west-2

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Looking at [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/simplify-machine-learning-with-xgboost-and-amazon-sagemaker/), specifically:

```
containers = {'us-west-2': '433757028032.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'us-east-1': '811284229777.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'us-east-2': '825641698319.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'eu-west-1': '685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest'}

sess = sagemaker.Session()

xgb = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(containers[boto3.Session().region_name],
                                    role, 
                                    instance_count=1, 
                                    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                                    output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
                                    sagemaker_session=sess)
```

where do these entries (contain image names?):

```
'685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest'
```

come from? I am especially after a eu-west-2 one - hope there is one (-: Thanks!

PS:

It may be that I can just run - at run time?:

```
from sagemaker import image_uris
image_uris.retrieve(framework='xgboost', region='eu-west-2', version='latest')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but those are the container registry path and you can find the full list [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-algo-docker-registry-paths.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use this code snippet:

```
from sagemaker import image_uris
image_uris.retrieve(framework='xgboost', region='eu-west-2', version='latest')
```

and it will give you this value:

> 644912444149.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest

This is the latest version of the container but it not recommended to run in prod environments.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-algo-docker-registry-paths.html